# How set name to usercontrol in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I've created UserControl and I don't know how to set Name property when I use it.

```
<my:LabelListBox Margin="12,314,480,12"/>
```

I need to access this control from my code. But without name, I don't know how.

Comment: Can't you use x:Name with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
<my:LabelListBox x:Name="MyName" Margin="12,314,480,12"/>
```

Comment: Sure, I'll do this, but after 8 minutes) It's to early to accept it)

Comment: Best. WPF. Answer. Ever.